# Simultaneous trig equations query

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I have a quick question to confirm something:

Given two trigonometric equations $$a = \cos \beta~~~\text{and}~~~b = \sin \beta \cos \alpha$$

Am I correct to state that if we know $a$ and $b$ (where $0 \leq \beta \leq \pi$) and ($0 \leq \alpha \leq 2 \pi$) then we can find $\beta$ and $\alpha$ without any sign ambinguity and hence there is no further information required. This follows since $\beta = \cos^{-1}(a)$ which implies $\alpha = \cos^{-1}(\frac{b}{\sin(\beta)})$? Would the additional piece of information of knowing the sign of $\sin \beta \sin \alpha$ allow you ta calculate $\beta$ and $\alpha$ without sign ambinguity?

Comment: Where does $\alpha,\beta $ belong their domain and range of $arccos$ and $ arcsin $ if same then no worries

Comment: If, as you say, $0\le\beta$ and $0\le\alpha$, then there is no sign ambiguity on $\alpha$ or $\beta$ regardless of what any other conditions may be. But you must allow for the possibility that $\pi<\alpha\le2\pi$, whereas $0\le\cos^{-1}(\frac{b}{\sin(\beta)})\le\pi$.

Comment: Here is a counterexample: Let $\alpha=\dfrac{4\pi}{3},\,\beta=\dfrac{\pi}{6}$. In this case, $\cos^{-1}(\frac{b}{\sin(\beta)})=\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$ not $\dfrac{4\pi}{3}$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I agree with you 100% thanks for your time.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There is an obvious sign ambiguity on $\alpha$, as the cosine is an even function.

And there is also an indirect sign ambiguity on $\beta$, because a change of sign of $\beta$ can be compensated by supplementing $\alpha$.

---

Form the first equation,

$$\beta=2k\pi\pm\arccos a.$$

And from the second,

$$\alpha=2k'\pi\pm\arccos\frac b{\sin\beta}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For the first equation firstly, isn't it assumed by convention that we consider arccos in the range $0$ to $\pi$? Therefore $\beta \in [0, \pi]$? But that would be a restriction on $a$ which I would have to specify?

Comment: @Moses: there is no $\arccos$ in the given equation ! Trust my solution. Obviously, $|a|\le1,|b|\le\sqrt{1-a^2}$ for  a solution to exist.

Comment: I forgot to write the restriction on $\alpha$ and $\beta$, I updated now.

Comment: @Moses: the solution is still not unique.

Comment: $\beta$ is unique now and I guess it is just the sign of $\alpha$ which is not unique, since now $\alpha = \pm arccos \frac{b}{\sin \beta}$

Comment: @moses: no, $\alpha$ is known to be positive.

Comment: How is the solution then still not unique as you stated?

Comment: @Moses: check my answer. Taking into account the range of variation of the unknowns, you still have two solutions.

Comment: Since $0 \leq \beta \leq \pi \implies \beta = \text{arccos }  a$ since $0 \leq\alpha \leq 2\pi \implies k' = 0$ and $ \beta = \text{arccos } a$ implies $\alpha = \text{arccos}\frac{b}{\sin \beta}$. What is the problem with the reasoning?

Comment: @Moses: Now find the other solution.